# Is there a flexible way to vertically center top line of text box beside image?

Tags: html, css, image, alignment, center

Seems quite easy, but I couldn't figure out the right css balance.

What I want, is this result(orange block is image):

[image]

This is easy, if the image has fixed height and text fixed properties (line-height etc.), but I need this to work, even if I insert it into different places on my website, it needs to **automatically adjust to the size of image and text properties**. So if image gets bigger, or text has different size / line-height, it still works. I might omit text variations, but different-sized images need to work.

So far, I only got `display: flex` with `align-items: center`, but that works only for one line, once it breaks to new line, it centers the whole text block, which is wrong. There's gotta be some css trick to achieve this, right?

EDIT:
After another trial, I managed to come up with something better, but the text still needs to be controlled (top value of text must be: line-height / -2)

```css
.txticon {max-width: 250px; display: block; margin-bottom: 15px; display: flex;}
.txticon::after {content: ""; clear: both; display: table;}
.txticon img {float: left; margin-right: 10px;}
.txticon span {line-height: 20px; top: -10px; position: relative; overflow: hidden; transform: translateY(50%);}
```

```html
<a class="txticon" href="#">
  <img class="icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="">
  <span>One line text</span>
</a>
<a class="txticon" href="#">
  <img class="icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="">
  <span>Multiple line text which is really really really long</span>
</a>
```

Comment: *"There's gotta be some css trick to achieve this, right?"* and no, probably not.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="row">
  <img />
  <p>Text</p>
</div>

.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

This might work.

Comment: It works, but only for one line. Once the text line breaks, then the whole text box is centered, whereas what I want is the first top example of the image (to have the first text line centered to the image and other lines continue below)

Comment: Ok fine then give a class to <p> and `margin-top: 50%;` give this to that particular class, it will work.

Comment: That doesn't work at all I'm afraid. If I take your above code directly and then apply your edit with the margin-top, it stretches across available space and also does not center.

Comment: @maeros Have you got the answer yet?

Comment: If Yes then kindly provide the solution you found.

Comment: Sadly not. The best solution so far for me remains the one I inserted into my original question after the "EDIT" part.

Answer (score -1):

Would a `margin-top` on the text block work?

```html
<div class="row">
  <img />
  <p class="text">Text</p>
</div>
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.text {
  margin-top: 10px; // replace with half of the image height
}
```

Comment: This works, but you need to adjust it every time the image size changes, which is not very flexible.

Comment: I see. Then I can't think of a solution which doesn't involve using css variables or using styled components with javascript.

Comment: css variables are not such a big problem, I use SASS often.. Depends how you mean it though. And js is not really ideal yeah.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).